# How do I make my running numbers stop at a specified number and remain that way?

Tags: javascript, timer, counter, clock, stopwatch

```
function pad(val) {
  return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
setInterval(function() {
  $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec % 25000));
}, 1);
```

I simply want these seconds to stop at 25,000 and remain that way unless the page is obviously refreshed...what can I add to this code?

Comment: As of right now, it just resets at 25,000 and starts over. I know it says seconds but its simply just counting to 25,000, so no time/clock based actions are necessary

Comment: `setInterval(function, 1)` is executing the function every 1 **millisecond**, and intervals do not terminate unless you logically terminate them.

Comment: Also, you should take a look at `String.prototype.padStart()`  Example, put this in your browser console: `'hey there'.padStart(25, ' ')`

Comment: Thank you all! I got it working

Answer (score 2):

you could just add an if statement.

```js
let sec = 0;
function pad(val) {
  return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}
setInterval(function() {
  if (sec < 25000) {
    $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec % 25000));
  }
}, 1);
```

and if you want to clear interval so it stops running all together

```js
const countUp = setInterval(function() {
  if (sec < 25000) {
    $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec % 25000));
  } else {
    clearInterval(countUp);
  }
}, 1);
```